# Unpacked javascript code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I found this script (http://coolersport.info/) and downloaded it.
I want change some things in javascript code, so I opened cshout.js (unpacked version) and do changes. I saved it as "cshout.packed.js" (replaced with original packed version).

But now I go to my script index, I can't see any thing, And I see only a white black page...

Why unpacked version doesn't work? The packed version was create from original unpacked file ....
(I have same problem with some other scripts ... it is a example!)