# Unpacked javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I found this script (http://coolersport.info/) and downloaded it. I want change some things in javascript code, so I opened cshout.js (unpacked version) and do changes. I saved it as "cshout.packed.js" (replaced with original packed version).

But now I go to my script index, I can't see any thing, And I see only a white blank page...

Why unpacked version doesn't work? The packed version was create from original unpacked file  (I have same problem with some other scripts...it is an example!)

I debugging it with FireBug. Firebug said:

```
ajaxCS is not defined
localhost/cshout/cshout.js Line 49
cshout is not defined localhost/cshout
Line 14
```

Comment: I don't know why my text has large size! I don't add any special formatting code ...

Comment: You shouldn't post the same question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308329/unpacked-javascript-code-doesnt-work); filed a merge request.

Comment: A *white*, *black* page? What kind of electromagnetic spectrum do you see that I can't?

Comment: Ok, but my problem sloved. please lock this page ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for problem in wrong place

you need to include ajaxcs.js

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Javascript debugger such as the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox and trace down what has broken using that. Without the javascript we can't help in determining the issue.

Comment: Firebug said: ajaxCS is not defined
http://localhost/cshout/cshout.js
Line 49                     --------    cshout is not defined
http://localhost/cshout/
Line 14

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a syntax error in your code (referencing an unknown variable - typo?). If you copy your modified `cshout.js` to `cshout.packed.js` and it doesn't work, it means you broke something when you modified the original library.

Comment: But when I unpacked the packed.js file with "www.strictly-software.com/unpacker", and replace with packed text in packed.js, the javascript doesn't work!